# Delaying the state change of JCheckbox

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I'd like to make a Swing JCheckBox behave like this:

- When the user clicks it, a message is sent to the server, with the opposite of the checkbox' current checked state (`!checked`). That state doesn't actually change immediately.
- Some time later, the server responds with the new state for the checkbox.

I presume this is a pretty common usage pattern. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I think it is not a pretty common usage pattern to give the User no feedback on his click

Comment: @oliholz: I guess you're right, but the other way around would be to change the check, then later revert it if the server says "can't do". A good middle ground would be some sort of changing/loading indicator, but I don't suppose JCheckBox has it.

Comment: I would prefer start a own loading indicator and use [VetoableChangeSupport](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/VetoableChangeSupport.html) which can throw a `PropertyVetoException`

Comment: definitely against letting the user wait for a single widget state change. Would re-think the interaction: start off with the checkbox disabled in a valid state, ask the server if the other state is allowed and enable only if so.

Comment: But what if the Server doesn't know everytime if the other state is allowed. I would check by a 'save'-Button not single select. But your right VetoableChangeSupport doesn't fit either.

Comment: Can the user's click be cancelled before the response arrives?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at PropertyChangeSupport. [This article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/properties/bound.html) may give you some hints on how to implement what you want.

Comment: Hmm ... dont see how that class/article is related to the problem, care to elaborate?